# JQUERY - Get data from multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How could I do to get data from this HTML code :

```
<div id="indic">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Statistiques collecte :</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="indication[]" value="nbApp" />Nombre
        <input type="checkbox" name="indication[]" value="nbApp2" />Nombre2<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="indication[]" value="nbTel" />Nombre3
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Thank you :)

**EDIT :**

This is the solution :

```
$.each($('#indic input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function(i, v) {
    console.log($(v).val())
});
```

Comment: what data do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what data you are talking about but you could get the value of each checkbox by the following:

```
$.each($('input[type="checkbox"]'), function(i, v) {
     console.log($(v).val())
});
```

Comment: What data do you expect to get?

Comment: Take a look, it should be `$(v)` not `v`.

Answer (score 0):

create a button, then on click write try this

```
<input type="button" id="MyData" name="MyData" value="Save" />

$(function(){
  $('#MyData').click(function(){
    var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
    });
  });
});
```